# How to validate a dynamic xpath/href of edit/delete button of a list using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am validating an application where after creating a link that is showing on a list where all other same types of links are present. When I inspect the element of displayed links on the list I am getting a "HREF" with the same sequence but on last numerical number is showing which is dynamic. So my question is that how can I validate this using selenium web driver after creating a new link and then clicking on this link.

**Example of the HREF pattern: /admin/dashboard/quicklink/edit/2-->when I create another new link the href of the new link becomes /admin/dashboard/quicklink/edit/3. How can I locate this dynamic href?**

My purpose is that the link which have been created when I run the code and without changing my code I want to click the newly created link after creation

Comment: Share your current code

Comment: Relevant _HTML_ and your code trials please.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** if the number of newly created link will always greater than exists links

steps of code:

1. find all links and save into a List after create new link
2. sort the List by last number
3. get the first or last link in sorted List dependent the sorting order

**Option 2** Don't care  newly created link use greater number

steps of code:

1. find all links before create new link, and save all links' `href` value into  `List1`
2. create new link
3. find all links again and save all links' `href` value into `List2`
4. Compare `List1` and `List2` to find the different `href`, then use this `href` to find link to click